# Best strategy to avoid static initializer

Tags: java

I am migrating some legacy code to the new platform and legacy platform has static initializer. like

```
private final static long var;

static {
 var = Long.parseLong(System.getProperty("var.proerty"));
}
```

I wants to avoid that in my new code. Could some one tell me what is the best strategy to avoid it. Can I simply create var as a static variable and initialize it at the same time. like

```
private final static Long var = Long.parseLong(System.getProperty("var.proerty"));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid that, specifically?  Is that something that you really need on a per-class basis?  It looks to me like that will be a static thing and is not really applicable instance by instance, in which case that suggests it should also be `final`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. The reason I am trying to avoid to ease out the method to write automated test case.

Comment: How does this affect the wrrting of your automated test cases?

Comment: Guess I am not following the need exactly..  I don't see why you can't have `static` in an automated test case.  IIRC, unless you are using the class - the JVM won't even load it, thus not adding any overhead for normal runs (and with a single `long`, it's not much regardless).

Comment: No I think the OP wants to declare and initialize a static variable at the same time... Oh and also he wants to use a method to initialize the variable. Am I correct?

Comment: The solution you suggest will work, as long as the objects you refer to are valid at the time the initialization occurs.

Comment: is static block treated as legacy already?

Comment: My mind is still stuck on the first revision and the wording of "create var as an instance variable" - implying removing from static, looks like @Sierox is probably right in what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @all thank you very much for all the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question *Can I simply create var as a instance variable and initialize it?* is **Yes**:

```
private final static String var = System.getProperty("var.property");
```

is a perfectly acceptable form of initialization.

Note `String` vs. `Long` — `System.getProperty()` returns a String, you will have to convert it to a Long if that's what you want.

That said, there are other good reasons to use static initializer blocks, such as creating and populating a more complex data structure.

Comment: I would suggest you modify your answer, since your code example doesn't show an _instance variable_ being initialized. This is a static variable, not an instance variable. This should be made clear to the OP and future readers I believe.

Comment: @Laf the OP says *var as a instance variable* but the code shown by the OP following that uses `private final static`.  There is a discrepancy in the question, and I chose to go with the code shown in the question.

Comment: @StephenP I have edited the question after the suggestion. Thank you for your response.